# Indexing files from sub directories in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I need to index files from two sub directory inside a main directory using Lucene.

**Folder Structure**

Main Folder

|---SubDirectory1

|---SubDirectory2

Tried this

`String dataDir = "src\\main\\resources\\MainFolder";`

I thought it will go inside sub directory and index the files in sub folders also but no, zero file indexed.

Is there any way do this/method in Lucene or should I create two indexes for each sub folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene doesn't crawl through directories and index files for you. How would it know what attributes you want to index? That is something that you must do yourself. Have a look at the [IndexFiles demo class](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_2/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexFiles.html) provided by Apache in their tutorials for an example of how to do this. It might be worth copying the code into an IDE so it's easier to read, because there are a *lot* of comments in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I am new to this, I thought there might be some API method for this. Now, I have created seperate index for each folder.